# How to Animate bottle Cap breaking?

Tags: animation, rigging

I want to animate this Tamperproof cap. This is the example I am referring to [image]
I have tried using bend modifier and curve but I am not getting the same effect as required.

Comment: is the animation what you have or what you wanna have?

Comment: I want to make similar type of Animation

Answer (score 8):

You can parent the hole ring to an armature, activate the Auto-IK option and keyframe the opening:

[image]

Here segmented b-bones (to make it look more flexible, needs to be improved) but it doesn't look like segmented b-bones in your animated gif:

[image]

To segment bones, select them all in *Edit* mode, go into the *Bone panel > Bendy Bones*, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> on the value and type the value you want (for example 5):

[image]

If you switch the *Viewport Display* to *B-Bone* you'll see the segmentation (to reduce the bone thickness select all and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

Note that it will need more than 4 bones to get something correct.

Comment: Can you please show me the steps for Segmented b-bones 
or any tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the steps